# regex to break all chars between matching criteria

Tags: regex

Need help in building the regex for getting all chars separately between the matching criteria.

e.g.
Description is

> 1STARTDESCdescENDDESC2STARTDESCdescENDDESC3STARTDESCdescENDDESC4STARTDESCdescENDDESC5STARTDESCdescENDDESC6STARTDESCdescENDDESC7STARTDESCvalveENDDESC8STARTDESCvalveENDDESC9STARTDESCvalveENDDESC10STARTDESCvalveENDDESC

and regex is

```
((((\d+STARTDESC))((?!STARTDESC).)*(.)((?!STARTDESC).)*((ENDDESC))))
```

if we change this regex to

```
((((\d+STARTDESC))((?!STARTDESC).)*(desc)((?!STARTDESC).)*((ENDDESC))))
```

it will match all desc description.
need regex to match anything between `\dSTARTDESC`  and end with `ENDDESC` and get all chars separately.
like here I would need `d,e,s,c` and `v,a,l,v,e`.

Comment: Can't you just split the resulting matches? What is the language you are using for this task? Note it is possible to do with some regex falvors with one regex, but it will be rather unreadable.

Comment: Just FYI: https://regex101.com/r/oN4aS7/1

Comment: I am using Regex with JAVA. I was trying to use replaceAll function and was trying to replace these things in a single call.

Comment: Replace what with what? Please illustrate that in the question.

Comment: ohh k sorry for the incomplete information. It should match everything between STARTDESC and ENDDESC and replace the text per char. Like in my above example , if DUMMY is my replace text , then it should match desc and will replace all the chars with DUMMY , so newly generated text would be DUMMYDUMMYDUMMYDUMMY as desc contains 4 chars.

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/oN4aS7/2)? Check [this code, too](https://ideone.com/QBsqsy).

Comment: If my answer does not help you solve the issue, please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex based on a custom boundary specified with a `\G` operator + a tempered greedy token to make sure we only match single characters up to the `STARTDESC` or `ENDDESC`:

```
(\d+STARTDESC|(?!^)\G).(?=(?:(?!(?:START|END)DESC).)*ENDDESC)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oN4aS7/2). Use `Pattern.DOTALL` if the `desc` can actually contain newline symbols.

Pattern breakdown:

- `(\d+STARTDESC|(?!^)\G)` - matches one or more digits (`\d+`) followed with `STARTDESC` or the location after the last successful match (`(?!^)\G`)
- `.`  - any character but a newline (with `Pattern.DOTALL`, any character), but only if followed with...
- `(?=(?:(?!(?:START|END)DESC).)*ENDDESC)` - `ENDDESC` that is not preceded with `STARTDESC` or `ENDDESC`.

A full [IDEONE code demo](https://ideone.com/QBsqsy):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "1STARTDESCdescENDDESC2STARTDESCdescENDDESC3STARTDESCdescENDDESC4STARTDESCdescENDDESC5STARTDESCdescENDDESC6STARTDESCdescENDDESC7STARTDESCvalveENDDESC8STARTDESCvalveENDDESC9STARTDESCvalveENDDESC10STARTDESCvalveENDDESC"; 
        String pattern = "(\\d+STARTDESC|(?!^)\\G).(?=(?:(?!(?:START|END)DESC).)*ENDDESC)";
        String subst = "$1DUMMY";
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll(pattern, subst));
    }
}
```